# Receiving webhooks from other site in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, webhooks, instamojo

I am developing a plugin for courier management system
The plugin includes payment gateway (Instamojo) integration. 
Successfully completed payment gateway integration by creating payment request.
In the payment process, This payment gateway will gives detailed data of transaction using webhooks. Im unable to get values from webhooks in wordpress
**My try** 
The code for initiating payment is down below,

```
try {
$response = $api->paymentRequestCreate(array(
    "buyer_name" => $_POST['name_f'],
     "purpose" => "#order :".$info_f['serno'],
    "amount" => $info_f['totalprice'],
   "send_email" => true,
    "email" => $info_f['emailid'],
    "redirect_url" => "http://www.mywebsite.in/thank-you",
    "webhook" => "http://www.mywebsite.in/thank-you"
    ));
    print_r($response);
    header('Location:'.$response['longurl']);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
   print('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
 }
```

(**Not sure about webhook url**)
Now at the thank you page, i have added a shortcode [cm-thankyou], the function is in thankyou.php

```
function cm_redback(){

echo "THANK YOU<br>";
print_r($_POST);
 }
add_shortcode( 'cm-thankyou', 'cm_redback' );
```

I tried printing the $_POST (i heard webhooks will be in $_POST) but unable to get the webhook working. 
Please help me to get this working, I searched a lot in google and hit dead-end without getting any results.
*These are instamojo integration guides, i referred.*
https://docs.instamojo.com/docs/payments-api
https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you havent mentioned whats the error is

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, The output of the shortcode is Aarray(), That's it

Comment: well then is the url appended with anything? if not there are no values returned, its either post or get

Comment: That's where i confused. This gateway has 2 types of response, That sends payment id in URL, so that i can use GET. But the gateway sends further information through webhooks (documentation said) so that i can use post (thats not working in this code). Bit confusion in webhook URL also. Don't know which to add there..

Comment: never mind the term webhooks ....you can $_POST information to a page but if $_POST is empty no data was sent. If the gateway did not specify what information would be sent by post, i'd look else where

Comment: So, What I'm doing is right in this code?, and i need some clarification on this: They mentioned - "Webhook is the URL to which we send the payment details as a POST request. Note that the content type of this request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded." Please explain this, Thank you :)

Comment: im not going to look into it too much but id say their webhook field is seperate to the redirect, i.e. the user is redirected to the `redirect` value and seperate to this, the gateway performs a post to the webhook. Try setting up something with a log file to see if information is returned. You won't see any output as a user